# Go elasticsearch insert bulk data from incoming pulsar

Tags: go, elasticsearch, bulk

I have to use goelastic library inserting the datas bulkly from coming pulsar. But i have a problem.

Firstly, pulsar send 1000 datas per partial bulkly. Then when i insert the elastic, there are a problem sometimes. This problem is attached. This problem cause data loss. Thanks for answer...
`ERROR: circuit_breaking_exception: [parent] Data too large, data for [indices:data/write/bulk[s]] would be [524374312/500mb], which is larger than the limit of [510027366/486.3mb], real usage: [524323448/500mb], new bytes reserved: [50864/49.6kb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=160771183/153.3mb, in_flight_requests=50864/49.6kb, model_inference=0/0b, eql_sequence=0/0b, accounting=6898128/6.5mb]`

This section is bulk code.

```
func InsertElastic(y []models.CP, ElasticStruct *config.ElasticStruct) {
    fmt.Println("------------------")
    bi, err := esutil.NewBulkIndexer(esutil.BulkIndexerConfig{
        Index:      enum.IndexName,
        Client:     ElasticStruct.Client,
        FlushBytes: 10e+6,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    start := time.Now().UTC()

    for _, x := range y {
        data, err := json.Marshal(x)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        err = bi.Add(
            context.Background(),
            esutil.BulkIndexerItem{
                Action: "index",

                Body: bytes.NewReader(data),

                OnSuccess: func(ctx context.Context, item esutil.BulkIndexerItem, res esutil.BulkIndexerResponseItem) {
                    i++
                },

                OnFailure: func(ctx context.Context, item esutil.BulkIndexerItem, res esutil.BulkIndexerResponseItem, err error) {
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Printf("ERROR: %s", err)
                    } else {
                        log.Printf("ERROR: %s: %s", res.Error.Type, res.Error.Reason)
                    }
                },
            },
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Unexpected error: %s", err)
        }
        x++

    }
    if err := bi.Close(context.Background()); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unexpected error: %s", err)
    }
    dur := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(dur)
    fmt.Println("Success writing data to elastic : ", i)
    fmt.Println("Success incoming data from pulsar : ", x)
    fmt.Println("Difference : ", x-i)
    fmt.Println("Now : ", time.Now().UTC().String())
    if i < x {
        fmt.Println("FATAL")
    }
    fmt.Println("------------------")

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

It seems like you do not have enough JVM heap on your node.

You are hitting a [circuit breaker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html) to avoid Elasticsearch to be Out Of Memory(OOM).

## Solution(s)

- Increase the JVM memory, you will find [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html) some documentation to size your nodes.
- Smaller bulk request

Comment: How to decrease bulk request size ?

Comment: I think `BulkIndexer` has a parameter named `Flushbytes` default at `5 mb` make it smaller and you should be good to go.